# Material ui : how to increase MuiModal-root z-index?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

By default z-index is set to 1300

doing something like:

```
[class*='MuiModal-root'] {
  z-index: 2000!important;
}
```

works but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Theme if you don't have one [Material-UI themes docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/) and override the z-index like so:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiModal:{
            root: {
                zIndex: 2000,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In MUI 5, it can be done like this.

```
<Dialog sx={{ zIndex: 10005 }}>.... </Dialog>
```

Docs [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/#Dialog-prop-sx)

[image]